# Error on deploying Playwright on a Streamlit server?

Tags: python, playwright, streamlit

Basically the title, I am facing a hurdle installing a playwright dependencies on a streamlit server while deploying. I have added

```
os.system('playwright install')
```

and

```
os.system('playwright install-deps')
```

but the below error persists.

```
Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers. ║

║ Please install them with the following command: ║

║ ║

║ sudo playwright install-deps ║

║ ║

║ Alternatively, use apt: ║

║ sudo apt-get install libnss3\ ║

║ libnspr4\ ║

║ libatk1.0-0\ ║

║ libatk-bridge2.0-0\ ║

║ libcups2\ ║

║ libdrm2\ ║

║ libatspi2.0-0\ ║

║ libxcomposite1\ ║

║ libxdamage1\ ║

║ libxfixes3\ ║

║ libxrandr2\ ║

║ libgbm1\ ║

║ libxkbcommon0\ ║

║ libpango-1.0-0\ ║

║ libcairo2\ ║

║ libasound2\ ║

║ libwayland-client0
```

Tried to deploy, works flawlessly on locahost but getting dependencies installation issue on a server.

Comment: Did you try adding `sudo` to your command, or using `apt`, like the error message suggests?

Comment: I did and it didn't recognize the sudo command and the server console shows the same error above. I have deployed from windows machine

Comment: You mean deployed on a Windows machine? The machine you deployed from doesn't seem terribly relevant. It's surprising that Playwright gives Linux-style commands on a Windows server...

Comment: The linux-style commands are given on a streamlit server. I have no idea where should add sudo command from my local machine

Comment: Are you trying to install playwright locally or on the server? Run whichever commands are necessary in whatever OS environment you want to install playwright. Generally, you shouldn't need to use `os.system` commands--I'd just SSH into a terminal and run it there, or use it as part of a deploy/build script, rather than in (presumably) the Python code.